# How to draw numbers with exceptions

Tags: c#, random

How to draw numbers with exceptions? For example I want to draw numbers between 1 and 4, but I dont't want to draw number 3.

I need it for my randomly movement function, I want to prevent certain movements.

```
void monsterMove()
{

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int movmentNumber = rnd.Next(1, 4);
    switch (movmentNumber)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.Clear();
            monster1PositionY = monster1.moveRight(monster1PositionY);
            map.movefillRightMonster(monster1PositionX, monster1PositionY);
            map.printBoard();
            break;

        case 2:
            Console.Clear();
            monster1PositionY = monster1.moveLeft(monster1PositionY);
            map.movefillLeftMonster(monster1PositionX, monster1PositionY);
            map.printBoard();
            break;

        case 3:
            Console.Clear();
            monster1PositionX = monster1.moveDown(monster1PositionX);
            map.movefillDownMonster(monster1PositionX, monster1PositionY);
            map.printBoard();
            break;

        case 4:
            Console.Clear();
            monster1PositionX = monster1.moveUp(monster1PositionX);
            map.movefillUpMonster(monster1PositionX, monster1PositionY);
            map.printBoard();
            break;
    }
}
```

I was looking for solution at stackoverflow and in other places, but coudn't find answer.

Comment: if movmentNumber  is equal to one of the ones you dont want (perhaps a list of ints) roll again until you got a int you like, now code it

Comment: I think i can use it, thank you, I was wondering if there is such a built-in function for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can maybe create an array of possible draws and select a random number corresponding to an index.

```
Random r = new Random();
int[] draws = new int[] {1, 2, 4};
int number = draws[r.Next(draws.Length)];
```

Edit: Oops it turns out that `r.Next(int max)` is exclusive, so it would be `draws.Length` and not `draws.Length-1`

Comment: I like this solution because it's similar to how a lot of games go about doing RNG elements.